# Anchor links (#) not working within the same page in Next.JS app router

Tags: reactjs, next.js, anchor, app-router, next-link

I have a `<Link/>` component with the `href` set to `#targetDiv` in my Next.js app. Ideally, when a user clicks on the button/link, the page should scroll to the respective section with the id `#targetDiv` . But it doesn't work that way.

I went through some of the other related posts here, and following the suggestions, I tried replacing the `<Link/>`  component with normal `<a></a>` tags. But it still doesn't work for me.

In both scenarios, when the user clicks the button/link, the url changes to `/about/#targetDiv`  and not `/about#targetDiv` . As a result the page scrolls to the top of the page instead

I'm using Next.Js version 13.4.9, with the new `/app` router. Surprisingly in the official documentation, even though the `/pages`  router mentions it, there is absolutely no mention of this in the official `/app` router documentation!

There are multiple GitHub issues created discussing the same problem, but either they have a confusing conclusion, where some people are claiming it's working fine for for them, while others claim its not.... or they conclude with building a separate functions/custom solutions to handle anchor links.

Is there really no other way to handle anchor-tags in Next.Js, besides building custom solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing with anchor links in Next.js is related to how the framework handles routing. By default, Next.js scrolls to the top of the page when the URL changes. To make anchor links work as expected, you can use the `react-scroll` library.

Here's how you can implement it:

1. First, install the `react-scroll` library:

```bash
npm install react-scroll
```

2. Import the necessary components from `react-scroll` in your component file:

```js
import { Link as ScrollLink, animateScroll as scroll } from "react-scroll";
```

3. Replace your `<Link>` component with the `ScrollLink` component:

```
<ScrollLink to="targetDiv" smooth={true} duration={500}>
  Click me
</ScrollLink>
```

4. Add an `id` to the section you want to scroll to:

```
<div id="targetDiv">
  ...
</div>
```

Now, when the user clicks on the link, it will smoothly scroll to the target section with the id `targetDiv`. Make sure to adjust the `smooth` and `duration` props according to your needs.

Keep in mind that this solution uses a third-party library. If you prefer not to use external dependencies, you would need to implement a custom solution using JavaScript scroll functions.